# Sharing image publicly from Slack channel

Tags: slack-api, slack

I have an outgoing webhook that listens to my public channel. When I post an image on the channel, I get a url for that image. However this url cannot be shared publicly since people need to be authenticated to view the message.

Is there any way I can generate a public link using the Slack API or is there no way around doing this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible with the API.

Here is what you need to do to get the public url for an image that was uploaded to a channel by a user:

1. Get the id of the posted image file with `files.list` using the user_id and timestamp you received through the outgoing webhook from Slack
2. Call `files.sharedPublicURL` to make the file public and receive a public url

Comment: Note that `files.sharedPublicURL` can't be called from a bot.

Comment: Not with the bot token, but you can call that method from a bot using the app token.